# How to map a set of numbers to another set.

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to do a mapping of 2 group of numbers so I can do an 'apples to apples' comparison.  The first group of numbers are price factors in certain zip codes ranging from .66 to 1.993.  My competitor also  has price factors,  but their range is from .62 to 2.14.  In order for me to put them on the 'same scale,'  I divided the min of both groups by each other and got 1.0645.  I then took my competitor data and multiplied each of their original factor by 1.0645 and that new table is my 'scaled' range.

Is this the right way to do this?  Is there a more accurate way?  I tried min,  max, and average,  and the results slightly differ,  so I don't know which one is the right one to use (if any)

Comment: If I understand your question, you have $a,b,c,d>0$ and you want to build a function $f:[a,b]\to [c,d]$? There are infinitely many such functions (with all kind of properties). I guess you'd like something increasing, continuous, bijective with $f(a)=c$ and $f(b)=d$, but there are still infinitely many such functions.

Comment: How you want to construct this comparison depends very heavily on what sort of information you need out of it. As Surb says, there are infinitely many functions that will map one to the domain of the other. A poorly chosen function may completely hide the critical facts, and completely mislead you. Without knowing what sort of information you are hoping to obtain from this comparison, we cannot guide you to a better choice.